# Php curl automatically set body in HTTP GET request

Tags: php, curl

Here is my issue. I have three environments (apache + mysql + mongoDB) : Continuous Integration, UAT and Prod.

All three environments are on a different VM hosted on the same proxmox and they are accessible through an nginx server.

I use Php curl to download CSV files. For a particular CSV file provider, php curl do not achieve to download the file on the Continuous Intergration environment while it does on UAT and Prod. After hours of investigation, the closest I came to the problem, I guess, is by outputting the request header.

As you can see below, on the Continuous Integration environment, php curl set the "Content-Length" header which suggest that it is sending a body within the GET request. I have not been able to debug this request body for now.

I really don't understand why would php curl add this request body on the CI environment especially when it does not do it in UAT and Prod env.

I also joined the php curl setup code.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
(Request Header in Continuous Integration Env)
------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Date: Mon, 15 Dec 2014 21:01:22 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 341
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/export/export<br />
does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>
-----------------------------------------

(Request Header UAT Env)
------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 15 Dec 2014 21:05:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

+ CSV data
----------------------------------------------
```

Php curl setup code :

```
public function getResource($url, $outputHeaders = false, $timeout = false)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36');

    // Follow redirections
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    // Use navigation cookies
    $cookieFilePath = APP . 'tmp' . DS . 'cookies' . DS . 'curl_cookie.txt';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFilePath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFilePath);

    // Trust any certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    if ($timeout) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    }

    if($outputHeaders)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        throw new Exception('Erreur Curl : ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    if(empty($data))
        throw new Exception('Curl returned an empty html page.');

    $encoding = self::getEncoding($ch, $data);

    $html['data'] = $data;
    $html['encoding'] = $encoding;
    $html['effective_url'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I was not outputting the request header but the response one.

I installed the MITM Proxy (http://mitmproxy.org/ - easy to install, easy to use) which allows traffic monitoring from terminal and I could see that curl was sending cookies when requesting from the Continuous Integration environment but that it was not sending any from the UAT environment.

Removing the sent cookies on the Continuous Integration environment solved the issue.